# Is Noetherian condition necessary for Exercise 8.1 of Matsumura?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Exercise 8.4 of Matsumura's book is below.

> If $A$ is a Noetherian ring, $I$ and $J$ are ideals of $A$, and $A$ is complete both for the $I$-adic and $J$-adic topologies, then A is also complete for the (I + J)- adic topology.

In this problem, is Noetherian condition necessary? We may solve it by, as suggested in the book's hint, taking the Cauchy sequence $\{x_{n}\}$ such that $x_{n+1}-x_{n} \in (I+J)^{n} \subseteq I^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}+J^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}$ says that $x_{n+1}-x_{n} = u_{n}+v_{n}$ for $u_{n} \in I^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}, v_{n} \in J^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}$, thus the sequence converges to $x=x_{1}+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}u_{2i+1} + \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}u_{2i}+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}v_{2i+1} + \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}v_{2i}$ converges since $A$ is $I$-complete and $J$-complete. Moreover $x$ is unique because of ($I$ and $J$)-completeness.

In this argument, I did not use the Noetherian condition. Do I miss something in my argument? Otherwise, is the Noetherian condition really necessary?

Comment: I believe showing that $x$ is unique requires a non-trivial argument. You have to show that if $x'\in A$ is another element such that $x-x'\in (I+J)^n$ for all $n\geq 0$, then $x=x'$. Since $A$ is $I$- and $J$-complete, $x=x'$ would follow if you could show $x-x'\in I^n$ for all $n\geq 0$, or $x-x'\in J^n$ for all $n\geq 0$. However, I don't see how that would work in general, without using some noetherian-specific tricks.

Comment: @FlorianAdler Thank you for your comment. I though $x$ is unique since the power series in the definition of $x$ converges due to $I$-completeness or $J$-completenes. Do you think that is not enough for showing the uniqueness of $x$?